# How to avoid exceptions with open telemetry + zipkin + python if service is not available?

Tags: python, zipkin, open-telemetry

I have successfully setup tracing using open telemetry with Zipkin exporter in my Python app. When I closed the docker container running Zipkin the app started (quite rightly) to throw exceptions. Since my preference is for app functionality/performance over trace availability i'd like to understand if there is a setup or configuration to ignore the fact that traces cannot be exported?

I briefly used Jaeger which I believe used UDP and so wouldn't care if I stopped or started the docker instance. It would suit me to have similar functionality.

I have considered selecting the exporter at runtime, one of console or Zipkin but then I would need to restart the app to change over.

Answer (score 0):

> Since my preference is for app functionality/performance over trace availability i'd like to understand if there is a setup or configuration to ignore the fact that traces cannot be exported?

This is indeed one of the basic requirements in the error handling principles of OTEL https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-specification/blob/main/specification/error-handling.md#basic-error-handling-principles.

The span processor implementation are made sure the any exception the might occur during export is caught and only logged for the visibility but never thrown into main application. You can verify it [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/main/opentelemetry-sdk/src/opentelemetry/sdk/trace/export/__init__.py#L98-L102) for `SimpleSpanProcessor`  and [here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/main/opentelemetry-sdk/src/opentelemetry/sdk/trace/export/__init__.py#L364-L369) for `BatchSpanProcessor`. You might want to share the case where you saw exceptions throw into application flow.